# independently update the state of a attribute of a item in an array which are return using map

Tags: reactjs, map-function

this is my entire code

```
import { FormButton } from "../../shared/SharedElements/Buttons";
import { Header } from "../../shared/SharedElements/SharedElements";
import \* as l from './CartElements';
import profilepic from '../../../Images/person2.jpg';
import Spinner from "../../shared/Spinner/Spinner";
import useFetch from "../../../Hooks/useFetch";
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import useAuth from "../../../Hooks/useAuth";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { MdCheckBox } from 'react-icons/md';
import { MdCheckBoxOutlineBlank } from 'react-icons/md';
import { AiFillPlusCircle } from 'react-icons/ai';
import { MdDelete } from 'react-icons/md';
import axios from "axios";
import { Link } from "@mui/material";
const CartComponent = ({data}) =\> {
const{user}=useAuth();
console.log(data);
const\[Items,setItem\] = useState(data);
const \[clickedIndex, setClickedIndex\] = useState({});
const\[selectItem,setSelectItem\] = useState();
const\[OrderItem,setOrderItem\] = useState({});

    const[Quantity,setQuantity] = useState(1);
    const quantityRef = useRef(Quantity);
    const[price,setPrice] = useState();
    
    
    //Select Item Independelntly
    const handleClick = async (index) =>{
        setClickedIndex(state => ({
        ...state, //copy previous state
        [index]: !state[index] //update value by index key
        }));
        setSelectItem(index);
        setOrderItem(Items[index]);
    };
    
    //Delete Cart Item
    const deleteCartItem = async ({cartId,foodId})=>{
        try {
            const formData = {cartId,foodId} 
            const res = await axios.patch('api/v1/Customer/RemoveCartItem',formData);
            console.log(res);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
        }
    }
    const selectOne = async (index)=>{
        const item = Items[index];
        const cartId = item.cartId;
        const foodId = item.id;
        console.log(item);
        await deleteCartItem({cartId,foodId});
        handleClick(index);
    }
    
    //Increase Quantity
    const AddQuantity = async ({foodId,quantity})=>{
        try {
        const formData = {foodId,quantity}
          const res = await axios.post('api/v1/Customer/Addtocart',formData);
          console.log(res);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error.message);
        }
      }
    
    const increaseQTY = async(index)=>{
        const item = Items[index];
        const foodId = item.id;
        handleClick(index);
        setQuantity(Quantity+1);
        quantityRef.current = Quantity+1;
        const quantity = quantityRef.current;
        console.log(quantity);
        await AddQuantity({foodId,quantity});
    }
    // console.log(quantity);
    return ( 
        <>
         <l.Container>
           <l.SubContainer>
            <l.SubSection1>
                <l.ProfileImage>
                    <l.Image src={`http://localhost:5000/images/${user?.ProfileImage}`}/>
                </l.ProfileImage>
                <l.Name>
                    {user?.Name}
                </l.Name>
            </l.SubSection1>
            <l.SubSection2>
                <Header>MY CART</Header>
            </l.SubSection2>
            <l.SubSection3>
                <l.Left>
                    {
                        data.map((cart,index)=>{
                            return(
                                <l.CartSection>
                                    {/* <l.SelectIcon onClick={()=>{selectOne(index)}}>
                                        {change && selectItem === index ? <MdCheckBox/> : `your text`<MdCheckBoxOutlineBlank />}
                                    </l.SelectIcon> */}
                                        <l.ItemsCard>
                                            <l.FoodImage>
                                                <l.Food src={`http://localhost:5000/Foodimages/${cart.image}`}/>
                                            </l.FoodImage>
                                            <l.Details>
                                                <l.MainText>
                                                    <l.FoodName>
                                                        {cart.name}
                                                    </l.FoodName>
                                                </l.MainText>
                                                <l.SubText>
                                                    {/* <l.Text>{cart.Size}</l.Text> */}
                                                    <l.Text>
                                                        Quantity : {Quantity || cart.quantity}
                                                    </l.Text>
                                                    <l.Text>
                                                        Price : {Quantity * cart.price}
                                                    </l.Text>
                                            </l.SubText>
                                        </l.Details>
                                        <l.Icon onClick={()=>increaseQTY(index)}>
                                            <AiFillPlusCircle/>
                                        </l.Icon>
                                        <l.Icon>
                                            <MdDelete onClick={()=>selectOne(index)}/>
                                        </l.Icon>
                                    </l.ItemsCard>
                                </l.CartSection>  
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </l.Left>
                <l.Right>
                    <l.Description>
                        <l.ItemTexts>
                            <l.Label>
                                Item :
                            </l.Label>
                            <l.Data>
                                
                            </l.Data>
                        </l.ItemTexts>
                        <l.ItemTexts>
                            <l.Label>
                                Quantity : {Quantity}
                            </l.Label>
                            <l.Data>
                                
                            </l.Data>
                        </l.ItemTexts>
                        <l.ItemTexts>
                            <l.Label>
                                Total Price : {Quantity * price}
                            </l.Label>
                            <l.Data>
                                
                            </l.Data>
                        </l.ItemTexts>
                        <l.ButtonSection>
                            <Link to='/CustomerPay'>
                                <FormButton>
                                    Order
                                </FormButton>
                            </Link>
                        </l.ButtonSection>
                    </l.Description>
                </l.Right>
            </l.SubSection3>
        </l.SubContainer>
        </l.Container>
        </>
     );

}

export default CartComponent;
```

i want increase quantity independenlty when i clicked specific item's plus icon then that increased quntity value should appear. In here when i click plus icon of a specific item it will increase the value of quantity of all items in front end but addQuantity function is worke properly it update quantity only clicked item and pass that value to backend issue is in frontend one

Comment: The quantity isnt increased or the total price isnt updated?

Comment: quantity is increased but not independntly when one item clicked it increased quantity of all items this will happen in frontend only backend part is working properly

Comment: You need to store in the state the items with the prices and change them everytime the quantity changes. You are using a useref for price but I think it dont works the way you think.